# What happens after posting bug to Postgres mailing list? When to expect response / fix?

Tags: untagged

I've posted bug report to Postgres mailing list ([BUG #5289: Unpredictable error in plpgsql function loop](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/2010-01/msg00173.php)).

Then I found even more simple code to expose error, so I've reported next bug (#5290, now waiting for approval).

What can I expect? When there be any response to this report? And if it will be confirmed - when to expect fix for it?

Put it in other words: how responsive is Postgres support / how long it takes for them to fix a bug?

Comment: Why are you asking here?

Comment: @John: i am responsible for selecting proper DBMS for our development team and for production environment as well, so it is very important to me what level of response time and support in general we may expect from PostgreSQL team. right now i have very serious problem with reported bug and i wanted to know i anyone here has experience with reporting postgres bugs (how these reports are handled). if serverfault is not good place to ask such questions, so where in better place for them?

Answer (score 2):

**This only answers the question indirectly, but...**

From: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#Where_can_I_get_support.3F

*"The PostgreSQL community provides assistance to many of its users via email. The main web site to subscribe to the email lists is http://www.postgresql.org/community/lists/. The general or bugs lists are a good place to start."*

**If that doesn't get the answer you want...**

*"The major IRC channel is #postgresql on Freenode (irc.freenode.net). A Spanish one also exists on the same network, (#postgresql-es), a French one, (#postgresqlfr), and a Brazilian one, (#postgresql-br). There is also a PostgreSQL channel on EFNet."*

**And if that fails, and the problem is important enough...**

*"A list of support companies is available at http://www.postgresql.org/support/professional_support."*

Answer (score 1):

They also have a [mailing list](http://www.postgresql.org/community/lists/), so you can ask your question there. Or use their [IRC channels](http://www.postgresql.org/community/irc).

In any case, this is a software, done by volunteers (in most part) in their free time. It's not really accepted behavior to push them too much. The usual answer will be anyway "it will be done when it's done".

Meanwhile, you can look in their bug database, and see how fast other cases were addressed, and you can make some estimate.

Comment: Mailing list you mentioned is where I've posted my bug report. PostreSQL pretends to be "The world's most advanced open source database", so it should not fail with simplest sql statements ;-). As a DB user for such popular and big (and advanced) DBMS as Postgres, I expect to have good support and fast bug fixes, especially for such general error in sql statement processing. Support's response time is one of main criteria on which DBMS should be chosen...

Comment: @WildWezyr - if you *pay* for support, yes: you should expect it to be within some SLA. If you do *not* pay for it, then it's when they get there. In my experience, that's tended to be quick, but it's still being done by folks whom you are not paying or compensating in any fashion...

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to shrink your example down to a more manageable size.